# Debugging HeapReAlloc() failure using GetExceptionCode()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, memory-management

I have a `HeapReAlloc()` failing with the error `ACCESS_VIOLATION`, but I'm unsure how to implement a further check using `GetExceptionCode()` as it uses try/catch or exception or something - can someone give me an example of how I can use it to narrow down this failure?

Answer (score 1):

You are trouble-shooting the wrong problem.  HeapRealloc() is bombing because the heap is corrupted.  That happened a while ago, some statement in your program overflowing a heap block, writing data to memory that was freed, something like that.  MSVC has a debug memory allocator to help you troubleshoot these kind of problems, look in the MSDN library for `<crtdbg.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `hHeap` and `lpMem` parameters of [`HeapReAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366704%28VS.85%29.aspx) are valid.
You should take the following possible root of causes into account.

- What value is passes for `dwFlags`.
- How `hHeap` is obtained.

  - via [`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599(v=VS.85).aspx)
  - or [`GetProcessHeap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366569(v=VS.85).aspx)
- What parameters are provided to `HeapCreate`/`GetProcessHeap`.

---

In addition to `HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, lpMem)`, you should also validate the entire heap by calling

```cpp
HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, NULL)
```

Comment: hHeap is valid, passing HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS | HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY for dwFlags, and lpMem is valid when I use HeapValidate just before the HeapReAlloc function call.

Comment: I use HeapCreate with the parameters HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS,100000,0

Comment: @Becky, in addition to `HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, lpMem)` can you *also* call `HeapValidate(hHeap, 0, NULL)` to validate the entire heap?